# Transform excel file with timeline in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

What is the best way to transform an Excel file with a timeline on the x-axis (and values for each month) into the format described below in MS SQL Server?

E.g. the excel file has the following format:
[image]

After the transformation the table in MS SQL Server should look like this:
[image]

What's the most efficient way to do this in MS SQL Server?

Comment: You want to use `UNPIVOT`. Upload the Excel into a working table as is, then `UNPIVOT` into the SQL Table you want.

Comment: Thanks. How would the SQL-Statement look like in the example mentioned above?

Comment: The most efficient way is probably to use excel.  Where does the sql-server requirement originate?

Comment: We did this task in MS Access + VBA before and I wondered how this task is solved in MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using unpivot, Please Try Following:

```
SELECT [name], [Description],Months, Mon
FROM
(
  SELECT [name], [Description], [Jan], [Feb],[mar],[Apr],[May],[June],[July]
  FROM yourtable
) AS n
UNPIVOT 
(
  Mon FOR Months IN ([Jan], [Feb],[mar],[Apr],[May],[June],[July])
) AS up;
```

My complete script is below for testing:

```
create table #temp
(
    [name] varchar(255),
    [Description] varchar(255),
    [Jan] int,
    [Feb] int,
    [Mar] int,
    [Apr] int,
    [May] int,
    [June] int,
    [July] int
)

insert into #temp
values('Name1','Description1',4,6,8,8,4,5,7)
,('Name2','Description2',9,7,7,5,8,1,8)
,('Name3','Description3',1,10,1,4,6,4,3)
,('Name4','Description4',6,7,1,7,3,2,1)
,('Name5','Description5',3,9,8,6,6,5,7)
,('Name6','Description6',10,2,5,9,10,8,10)
,('Name7','Description7',10,8,5,7,10,7,8)


SELECT [name], [Description],Months, Mon
FROM
(
  SELECT [name], [Description], [Jan], [Feb],[mar],[Apr],[May],[June],[July]
  FROM #temp
) AS n
UNPIVOT 
(
  Mon FOR Months IN ([Jan], [Feb],[mar],[Apr],[May],[June],[July])
) AS up;


drop table #temp
```